# How to add roles/groups to Subject in Websphere 8.5 JAAS?

Tags: websphere, jaas

I have LDAP authentication in Websphere 8.5 and I need map LDAP groups to groups from database in LoginModule.
Now I'm stuck on how to add groups to Subject?

For example, i'm have next role:

I'm tried add next values in LoginModule.commit function, but it's not working:

```
subject.getPrincipals().add(new WSPrincipalImpl("customRealm/my_role"));
subject.getPrincipals().add(new WSPrincipalImpl("some_role"));
subject.getPrincipals().add(new WSPrincipalImpl("some_role@customRealm"));
subject.getPrincipals().add(new WSPrincipalImpl("my_role"));
subject.getPrincipals().add(new WSPrincipalImpl("customRealm/my_role"));
subject.getPublicCredentials().add(new WSCredentialImpl("defaultWIMFileBasedRealm", "admin", "1", "group:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/cn=Admin,ou=Group,dc=rbs,dc=test,dc=local", "user:defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/cn=admin,ou=Users,dc=rbs,dc=test,dc=local", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("some_role@customRealm", "some_role")), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("group:customRealm/some_role"))));
```

For check user role I use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().isUserInRole(role)`

Answer (score 0):

I see you already added a group in the WSCredential; You can specify more than one groups as a list.
You can not add a group directly to a Subject.

Also, I see you added the roles in the WSPrincipalImpl; These roles are actually the principal names.

Regards,

Ut Le